# apache2ctl versus systemctl

Tags: shell-script, systemd, apache-httpd, services, start-stop-daemon

I'm wondering about the implications of using either `apache2ctl` or `systemctl`.

If I understand correctly one shouldn't use anything but Systemd's utility to control services but on the other hand `apache2ctl` has a few extra features. Does `systemctl` in turn call `apache2ctl` or does it go another route altogether?

Comment: systemd normally calls init scripts in /etc/init.d unless there is a custom systemd service script available for the process or you create one yourself. Normally, systemd and init service scripts only start, stop, restart and report the status of services. I would use systemd for these functions and apachectl for others.